# How can I import pyautogui without getting thrown an ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

import pyautogui throws an ERROR

```
Python 3.10.8 (main, Apr  9 2023, 15:38:43) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 43, in __init__
    raw = open(filename, 'rb').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/juan/.Xauthority'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 60, in __init__
    auth_name, auth_data = connect.get_auth(self.socket,
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 91, in get_auth
    return mod.get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 103, in new_get_auth
    au = xauth.Xauthority()
  File "/home/juan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 45, in __init__
    raise error.XauthError('~/.Xauthority: %s' % err)
Xlib.error.XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/juan/.Xauthority'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to uninstall pyautogui with: `pip uninstall pyautogui`,
then install it using this command: `python3 -m pip install pyautogui`,
This command is in the docs of [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).
I wish it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I've managed to overcome all the problems I had with Xauthority.
It seems that you need to create a directory named Xauthority.
But there is important information that is missing from your question, how are you trying to run the program? and from where? from which OS?
Is it a docker?

Here is a repo I wrote about how I managed to dockerize a python GUI:
https://github.com/DorinBe/PySurfs

Take a look at the readme and I will be happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are encountering is related to the Xlib library, which is used by PyAutoGUI for screen interaction. It appears that the library is unable to find the .Xauthority file in your home directory.

The .Xauthority file is used by X server to store authentication data. It is usually located in the user's home directory, but in your case, it seems to be missing.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check if the .Xauthority file exists in your home directory. Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
ls -la ~/.Xauthority
```

If the file doesn't exist, you may need to recreate it.

2. Re-create the .Xauthority file by running the following command in the terminal:

```
touch ~/.Xauthority
```

3. Change the permissions of the .Xauthority file to ensure that it is accessible. Run the following command:

```
chmod 600 ~/.Xauthority
```

4. Restart your computer to ensure that the changes take effect.
5. Try importing pyautogui again.

Hope this helps!